# How to concatenate (and not compile) several less files into one using grunt

Tags: gruntjs, less, grunt-contrib-less

I'm having trouble finding a solution to this problem. I have a less file `app.less` that only consists of `@import` statements. Now I want to generate a single less file that includes all imported less files, because I want to send it to the client to compile it there (yes, I have my reasons to do that).

So the less file should not be compiled in the grunt build step, but only concatenated, so that the client doesn't have to load several less files. I feel that this is a usecase that should have appeared for others as well when compiling less on the client, but I couldn't find a single solution. I don't care if the concatenation happens with `grunt-contrib-less` or any other tool.

Comment: Use [grunt-contrib-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat).

Comment: Ok, I suppose that's possible. But `grunt-contrib-concat` doesn't understand less' `@import`statements. Then I basically have to replace my `app.less` file with a `grunt-contrib-concat` configuration file, which I was looking to avoid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LESS docs says:

> Use @import (inline) to include external files, but not process them.

See: [Import At-Rules](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-atrules-feature) and [@import (inline)](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-atrules-feature-inline)

You could create new file, for example `concatenate.less` and import `.less` files with `inline` keyword. Then if you process it, it will work exactly like concatenation, no CSS is processed out of it.

**concatenate.less**

```
@import (inline) "file1.less"
@import (inline) "file2.less"
@import (inline) "file3.less"
```

And use your Grunt task like you used to, just rename output file extension to `.less` for clarity. Tested it, should give you exactly what you wanted.

**Nested imports**

As @seven-phases-max pointed out, that nested imports would be problem in this case.

Solution would be [grunt-includes](https://github.com/vanetix/grunt-includes).

- Use `grunt-includes` with `includeRegexp` option to create files listed in `concatenate.less` with already imported LESS files to some other folder.
- Change `concatenate.less` files paths to that folder.
- Run your LESS compiling Grunt task normally.

Comment: Nice spot. I've never seen using of `(inline)` like this before (well, this has its problems of not supporting nested imports, but still very neat).

Comment: Thanks @seven-phases-max! Yes, nested imports would be problem with this. Hopefully @Peter dosen't have nested imports in this case. But I'll try to find any good solution for nesting.

Comment: Thanks, that works indeed! And luckily I don't have any nested imports.

Comment: Actually I just realized what the downside of this is: Because the imported files are not being processed, all the comments remain in the concatenated less file, which makes it at least 20% longer than it needs to be. I'm now using [`grunt-stripcomments`](https://github.com/kkemple/grunt-stripcomments) to remove the comments.

Comment: Yes, it won't remove comments. It will just concatenate .less files, kust like you first asked. But nice solution.

Answer (score 4):

in case someone is working with gulp,

you can just create concatenate.less as @Rene Korss sugested, and use the same command as for compiling less.

Less outputs concatenate.css filename, which is misleading in our case,
so I'm using [gulp-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename) to have filename named as I want.

```
var src = 'path-to-concatenate-less-file';
var destination = 'path-to-destination';
gulp.task('concatenate-styles', function () {
    var compile= gulp.src(src)
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(rename('concatenate-all.less'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(destination))
    .pipe(notify("Saved file: <%= file.relative %>!"));
    compile.on('error', console.error.bind(console));
    return compile;
});
```

Example of concatenate.less:

```
@import (inline) "general.less";
@import (inline) "typography.less";
```